# MySQL login error (using password) - Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, root

I'm trying to login to MySQL on Mac OS X El Capitan and when I enter the command:

```
    mysql -u root -p
```

I am prompted to enter my password and then get the following error:

```
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've looked at the other threads about this question and none of them have helped me. Any assistance would be appreciated, as I'm still learning MySQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually shows up when you enter the wrong password for the MySQL user or try to connect with an username that does not exist for MySQL. Usually MySQL starts with no password/empty password for the root user, unless specified otherwise during the installation. So just

```
mysql -u root
```

should work in that case, without entering any password.

Needless to say that such a configuration is unsafe, because everyone with access to the machine could manipulate the database. Therefore it is highly recommended to set a password for the root user.

Comment: I tried that and got exactly the same error message, but with (using password: NO) instead of YES.